# Exception calling AddFieldAsXml with "1" argument

Tags: powershell, site-column, addfieldasxml

I am trying to add the column below via PowerShell

```
<Field 
    ID="{1920c575-d592-40eb-a163-5a302b78aa65}" 
    Type="Note" 
    DisplayName="1920c575d59240eba1635a302b78aa65" 
    StaticName="1920c575d59240eba1635a302b78aa65" 
    Name="1920c575d59240eba1635a302b78aa65" 
    Required="FALSE" 
    Hidden="TRUE" 
    Overwrite="TRUE" 
    ShowInNewForm ="FALSE" 
    ShowInEditForm="FALSE" 
    ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" 
/>
```

However I get this error message:

```
Exception calling "AddFieldAsXml" with "1" argument(s): ""
At line:14 char:9
+         $destWeb.fields.AddFieldAsXml($fld.OuterXml)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException
```

All other site columns are created correctly but not this one. I know this is related to a metadata column but at this point I am not sure if it is related. I have another identical column except the GUIDs that gets created with out problem. Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

I am using the code from this site http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/export-and-importcreate-site-columns-in.html

Comment: Can you show the code context that's running this? You should not have to provision the hidden Note columns that accompany Taxonomy columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have already created that field with that GUID.

What about if you export the columns? Do you get any field with that same GUID `1920c575-d592-40eb-a163-5a302b78aa65`? If you don't see it, try to **empty** site's recycle bin and try to re-run the script.

Another possibilty, it's that as Internal Name is being repeated and SharePoint is adding [one more character](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2009/04/static-name-vs-internal-name-vs-display-name-in-sharepoint/) to make it unique, and that would overcome the limit of [32 characters limit](http://benhuang.blogspot.com.es/2009/08/32-character-limit-in-sharepoint-lists.html). Try to change *Internal Name* to less characters.

Comment: Thank you. It was related to 32 characters limit. When use ID column to get the field I see the field is already there.